# How to filter a dictionary and append the result to a list?

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

class dataFilter:

> Constructor

```
def __init__(self, data_dict):

    self.filtered_data = []
    self.data_dict = data_dict
    self.age_group = ""
    self.gender = ""
    self.period = ""
    self.migration_background = ""

def filteredData(self, age_group, gender, period, migration_background):

    self.age_group = age_group
    self.gender = gender
    self.period = period
    self.migration_background = migration_background
```

> The problem is this if statement. For some reason I can't find another way to do this:

```
    for key in self.data_dict["value"]:
        if key["Leeftijd"] == self.age_group and key["Geslacht"] == self.gender and key["Perioden"] == self.period and key["Migratieachtergrond"] == self.migration_background:
            self.filtered_data.append(key)
    return self.filtered_data
```

> The error message

if key["Leeftijd"] == self.age_group and key["Geslacht"] == self.gender and key["Perioden"] == self.period and key["Migratieachtergrond"] == self.migration_background:
TypeError: string indices must be integers

> Expected input

```
age = "80007"
gender = "T001038"
period = "2000SJ00"
migrationbackground = "T001040"
```

> Expected output: After returning the list it will be printed to the screen like this for now.

```
{'1198188', 'T001038', '80007', 'T001040', '2000SJ00'}, 
{'1198189', 'T001038', '80007', 'T001040', '2000SJ00'},
{'1198190', 'T001038', '80007', 'T001040', '2000SJ00'},
{'1198191', 'T001038', '80007', 'T001040', '2000SJ00'},
{'1198192', 'T001038', '80007', 'T001040', '2000SJ00'}
```

> This is a small bit of the dictionary I use. It's really big so I'm not including the entire thing, but this is how it looks like

```
{
  "value": {
    "288": {
      "ID": 288,
      "Geslacht": "T001038",
      "Leeftijd": "80007  ",
      "Migratieachtergrond": "T001040",
      "RegioS": "PV31  ",
      "Perioden": "2000SJ00",
      "Hbo_8": "       0"
    },
    "289": {
      "ID": 289,
      "Geslacht": "T001038",
      "Leeftijd": "80007  ",
      "Migratieachtergrond": "T001040",
      "RegioS": "PV31  ",
      "Perioden": "2001SJ00",
      "Hbo_8": "       0"
    },
    "290": {
      "ID": 290,
      "Geslacht": "T001038",
      "Leeftijd": "80007  ",
      "Migratieachtergrond": "T001040",
      "RegioS": "PV31  ",
      "Perioden": "2002SJ00",
      "Hbo_8": "       0"
    },
    "291": {
      "ID": 291,
      "Geslacht": "T001038",
      "Leeftijd": "80007  ",
      "Migratieachtergrond": "T001040",
      "RegioS": "PV31  ",
      "Perioden": "2003SJ00",
      "Hbo_8": "       0"
    },
    "292": {
      "ID": 292,
      "Geslacht": "T001038",
      "Leeftijd": "80007  ",
      "Migratieachtergrond": "T001040",
      "RegioS": "PV31  ",
      "Perioden": "2004SJ00",
      "Hbo_8": "       0"
    },
    "293": {
      "ID": 293,
      "Geslacht": "T001038",
      "Leeftijd": "80007  ",
      "Migratieachtergrond": "T001040",
      "RegioS": "PV31  ",
      "Perioden": "2005SJ00",
      "Hbo_8": "       0"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: HI Gortex, can you maybe show an example of expected input and output pairs? The way it is right now it's a bit hard to know what exactly you want to do.

Comment: Hey Johannes, I hope It's a bit less confusing now. The data from the dictionary is from an external json file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in

```
for key in self.data_dict["value"]:
  # the type of key is `str`
```

For example,

```
    print([key for key in self.data_dict["value"]])
    # It prints ['288', '289', '290', '291', '292', '293']
```

You can do the following instead

```
    for key, nested_obj in self.data_dict["value"].items():
        if (
            nested_obj["Leeftijd"] == self.age_group
            and nested_obj["Geslacht"] == self.gender
            and nested_obj["Perioden"] == self.period
            and nested_obj["Migratieachtergrond"] == self.migration_background
        ):
            self.filtered_data.append(key
```

However, note that your input has trailing spaces (e.g., `"80007  " != "80007"`). You need to clean up the spaces first.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This solved my problem. I also forgot about the spaces in the strings, but that's fixed as well now.

Answer (score 0):

What this error basically saying is this that your key in for loop is string and you are considering it dictionary by passing dictionary keys but string have integer indices
So recheck your dictionary and run for loop accordingly

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So you are saying I can't use string indices on an instance of a for loop? I can't change the dictionary however because it's loaded from a json file which I'm not allowed to change

Comment: What I am saying is that your for loop is getting string values from dictionary instead of dictionaries so if you can show how your data dict looks I can help more

Comment: Oh yes. you're right. I included a part of my dictionary above. hehe